# How to select last floating point value in a string

Tags: java, regex

I have a string such as :

> "Hello i dont want to select 123.12 but 890.12 how do i do it "

---

From the above string, i want to select "890.12", i have already tried with **$**. 
For "890.12", it should be in the last but i am getting some words after "890.12".

Comment: Hint: there is no digit in the substring following the last number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per Huss has already given a very readable answer. As he mentioned, it is also possible to do it with one match, without looping:

```
private static String findLastDecimal(String string)
{
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(\\d+\\.\\d+)(?!.*\\d+\\.\\d+)").matcher(string);
    if (m.find())
    {
        return m.group(1);
    }
    return null;
}
```

The regex here looks for a decimal that is not followed by another decimal. It also works if there are integers or things like `.123` after the last "correct" decimal.

Comment: thanks @malte hartwig it worked though i had to add **?** in front of the decimal **.** because some time the value will be integer.

Answer (score 2):

You *can* find it with one regex match, but in order to keep things simple and readable I would suggest looping like this:

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\d+\\.\\d+").matcher(string);
String value = null;
while(m.find()) {
    value = m.group();
}
```

If value is null, the pattern was not found, else it is the last occurrence of the pattern.